# Click to ajax generated 'a' element

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, click

Can't execute `click()` on generated ajax `a` element. But I can select.

```
function cansel(){
    var cansel_button = document.getElementById('cansel_button');
    console.log(cansel_button);
    console.log('post');
    cansel_button.click();
}
```

And I got this log:

```
<a id=​"cansel_button" style=​"text-decoration:​none;​" class="" onclick="">​…​</a>​
post
extensions/event.js:185Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Object  has no method 'click'
    at cansel (unknown source)
    at unknown source
    at [object Object].dispatch (extensions/event.js:183:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (extensions/miscellaneous_bindings.js:177:22)
```

And yes, this is injected script from chrome extension.

UPD:
Injected page have trigger like `$('#element').live('click', function(){ })` and I need to execute this without any hacks.

Answer (score 1):

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) method returns [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element), which does not have `"click"` method you were trying to call. If you want to call `click` handler, then you need to use this:

```
 cansel_button.onclick();
```

instead of `cansel_button.click();`.

Comment: See my update question. cansel_button.onclick() didnt what i want, but dont do errors.

Comment: @RED You could define `function someClickHandler(){ }` function, and pass as handler to `$('#element').live('click', someClickHandler)`.Then whenever you want , call  `someClickHandler()` function.

Comment: @RED Not sure, what do you mean by 'hack' ?! Maybe I don't understand your problem. hmm

Comment: I have remote page with own scripts. Where is exist code like $('#element').live('click', function(){ }). I inject my script with simulate click to this #element. But i got error.

Comment: @RED Have you tried this -> `$('#element').trigger('click')` ?

Comment: @RED How about `"$('#element').live"` ? What is that, if not jQuery?

Comment: Thats local jQuery in scripts page. I cant use it. But i think problem in a element, becouse button's work how need.